# How to convert Excel negative value to Pandas negative value

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am a beginner in python pandas. I am working on a data-set named fortune_company. Data set are like below.

[image]
In this data-set for Profits_In_Million column there are some negative value which is indicating by red color and parenthesis.

but in pandas it's showing like below screenshot

[image]

I was trying to convert the data type Profits_In_Million column using below code

```
import pandas as pd
fortune.Profits_In_Million = fortune.Profits_In_Million.str.replace("$","").str.replace(",","").str.replace(")","").str.replace("(","-").str.strip()
fortune.Profits_In_Million.astype("float")
```

But I am getting the below error. Please someone help me one that. How I can convert this string datatype to float.

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '-'
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have no control over the cell format in Excel, the `converters` kwarg of `read_excel` can be used:

> converters : dict, default None
>
> Dict of functions for converting values in certain columns. Keys can
>   either be integers or column labels, values are functions that take
>   one input argument, the Excel cell content, and return the transformed
>   content.

From `read_excel`'s [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html).

```
def negative_converter(x):
    # a somewhat naive implementation
    if '(' in x:
        x = '-' + x.strip('()')
    return x


df = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx', converters={'Profits_In_Million': negative_converter})
print(df)
#      Profits_In_Million
#    0              $1000
#    1             -$1000
```

Note however that the values of this column are still strings and not numbers (`int`/`float`). You can quite easily implement the conversion in `negative_converter` (remove the the dollar sign, and most probably the comma as well), for example:

```
def negative_converter(x):
    # a somewhat naive implementation
    x = x.replace('$', '')
    if '(' in x:
        x = '-' + x.strip('()')
    return float(x)

df = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx', converters={'Profits_In_Million': negative_converter})
print(df)
#      Profits_In_Million
#    0             1000.0
#    1            -1000.0
```